# Calculate duration between two hours in Java

Tags: java, date, duration

I want to calculate the time difference (duration) between two hours (HH:mm:ss) in Java. Here, I've read several topics on this subject, but my problem is a little bit different.

I'm not able to use `Joda-Time`, as well.

**Example:**

```
input values:    12:03:00 
                 00:00:00

expected output: 11:57:00
```

Сode:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String startTime = sc.next();
    String endTime = sc.next();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date d1 = sdf.parse(startTime);
    Date d2 = sdf.parse(endTime);
    long elapsed = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

    String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(elapsed),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsed) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(elapsed)),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(elapsed) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsed)));

    if (elapsed > 0) {
        System.out.println(hms);
    } else {

        elapsed = elapsed * (-1); //otherwise, print hours with '-'

        String hms1 = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(elapsed),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsed) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(elapsed)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(elapsed) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsed)));

        System.out.println(hms1);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
expected output: 11:57:00

actual output:   12:03:00 //that's the problem
```

Comment: Please format your code indentation so that it's legible.

Comment: "'I m not able to use JodaTime,too :/" And you can use Java 8 ?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes in Java 8 and later. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Dear Down-Voter: Please leave a criticism along with your vote. Calculating elapsed time between a time-of-day and end-of-day is a legitimate question.

Comment: You could profit a lot when using an API which enables/models the time 24:00 (midnight at the end of the day) and has formatting capabilities for durations, too. Simple example using my library Time4J see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/MenoData/90bcd254fafda19b15b578130b0b59fe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic flaw here is that you want the NEAREST distance between two times. When you are constructing your date objects, even though you only format for Hour:Minute:Second it still stores the day/month/year etc... For the dates 12:03:00 and 00:00:00 it defaults them to the same day, so the difference from (Midnight to Noon) is what your getting not (Noon to Midnight) of the next day. The solution for you would be to check if the times are less than 12 (military time) and if so add 1 to the day.

Here's How you do it:

```
    String t1 = "12:03:00";
    String t2 = "00:00:00";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    Date d1 = sdf.parse(t1);
    Date d2 = sdf.parse(t2);
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTime(d1);
    c2.setTime(d2);

    if(c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 12) {
        c2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + 1);
    }
    long elapsed = c2.getTimeInMillis() - c1.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: Ok,but I can use only hours as input :/

Comment: I edited my answer with the solution. You can keep your input the same. The days will default to Jan 1st 1970. So the code above will make the 00:00:00 Date occur on Jan 2nd 1970.

Comment: Thank you!Perfect!

Comment: ,i've one last question.When i input: 00:00:00 and 00:00:00 the program prints 24:00:00 ( that is normal,'cause of next day and the 'Calendar').Have you any ideas,how i can change the output to 00:00:00 ?Maybe with one 'if' before if(c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 12).Something like: if(c2.getTimeInMillis() == (or equals) c1.getTimeInMillis()),but i'm not sure :)

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.between( 
    LocalTime.parse( "12:03:00" ) , 
    LocalTime.parse( "23:59:59.999999999" ) 
).plusNanos( 1 ).withNanos( 0 )
```

> PT11H57M

## Use a nanosecond

The modern approach uses the java.time classes.

The catch is that for time-of-day only, there is no midnight. So your `00:00` which you apparently intended for end-of-day is actually interpreted as start-of-day.

There is only the last nanosecond before the day ends. The `LocalTime` has a constant defined for that last nanosecond: [`LocalTime.MAX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MAX) = `23:59:59.999999999`

Since you care only about whole seconds, we can take advantage of that fractional second. If your ending time happens to be `00:00:00`, substitute `LocalTime.MAX`. Then calculate a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) object. You can add a single nanosecond and then truncate the resulting fractional second by setting the fractional second (the nanoseconds) to zero.

For ending times other than `00:00:00`, the math still works. Adding a nanosecond gets you `….000000001` fraction of second, and [`Duration::withNanos`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#withNanos-int-) will truncate that unwanted fraction.

```
// This code assumes the inputs are *always* in whole seconds, without any fraction-of-second.

LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse( "12:03:00" );
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.parse( "00:00:00" );

if( stop.equals( LocalTime.MIN ) ) {
    stop = LocalTime.MAX ; // `23:59:59.999999999`
}

Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop );
d = d.plusNanos( 1 ).withNanos( 0 ) ;

System.out.println( "start/stop: " + start + "/" + stop );
System.out.println( "d: " + d );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/S05B4C).

> PT11H57M

## Formatting

The output from `toString` is standard [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). The `Duration` class can parse such strings as well as generate them.

I strongly recommend *not* representing a span of time in time-of-day style, HH:MM:SS. This is ambiguous and often creates confusion when read by humans.

But if you insist on that format you must build the string yourself. The `Duration` class lacks a `format` method seen in other java.time class. Oddly, this class originally lacked methods to extract the parts, a number of days, of hours, of minutes, of seconds, and a fractional second. See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20827047) for discussion. Java 9 brings such methods, named `to…Part`.

While using Java 8, I suggest doing string manipulation of the ISO 8601 formatted output. Replace the `PT` with empty string. If there is an `M`, replace `H` with a colon. If there is an `S`, replace the `M` with a colon and replace the `S` with empty string. If no `S`, replace `M` with empty string. I believe you can find this code posted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That is the awesome solution!Now all i need is to format PT11H57M to 11:53:00.Thank you !

Comment: @DeanTwit See new section at bottom for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to do:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class HourTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2015-05-04T12:07:00");
        LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.parse("2015-05-04T00:00:00");

        long seconds = Math.abs(ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(ldt1, ldt2));

        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", seconds / 3600, (seconds / 60) % 60, seconds % 60);

        // Prints 12:07:00. I tried it.
        System.out.println(hms);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I'm pretty certain it's not. For one thing, ChronoUnit.between returns the strict number of hours (meaning it truncates minutes, etc.)

Comment: Thank you,but I'v just tried with 12:07:00 and 00:00:00 ,and it's print only : 00:00:00(i  tried with next day,too) :)

Comment: I run that program exactly as-is and it prints "12:07:00"

Comment: Ok,but the output should be: 11:53:00

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenient methods were introduced.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse("12:03:00");
        LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.parse("00:00:00");

        LocalDateTime startDateTime = today.atTime(startTime);
        LocalDateTime endDateTime = today.atTime(endTime);

        if (startDateTime.isAfter(endDateTime)) {
            endDateTime = endDateTime.with(LocalTime.MIN).plusDays(1).with(endTime);
        }

        Duration duration = Duration.between(startDateTime, endDateTime);
        // Default format
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedDuration = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHours(), duration.toMinutes() % 60,
                duration.toSeconds() % 60);
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedDuration = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(),
                duration.toSecondsPart());
        System.out.println(formattedDuration);
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT11H57M
11:57:00
11:57:00
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).