# SimpleDateFormat sometimes wrong hours formatting

Tags: java, simpledateformat, duration, milliseconds, gmt

I want to convert my timestamp into XXhours:YYminutes string. My approach sometimes works correctly unless it’s obtaining greater values. For example, the

193500000 -> 05hours:45minutes (Wrong, correct is 53hours:45minutes)
60300000 -> 16hours:45minutes (correct)
63900000 -> 17hours:45minutes (correct)
108000000-> 06hours:00minutes (Wrong, correct is 30hours:00minutes)
117000000 -> 08hours:30minutes (Wrong, correct is 32hours:30minutes)

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH'hours' mm'minutes'");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "GMT"));
    String string  = dateFormat.format(totalTime);
```

Comment: in Java Date is not a hour counter.

Comment: You're trying to output durations using a function that outputs dates. That's totally unsupported; Java is right here and you are wrong here. There are only 24 hours in a day so you will never get more than 24 for HH. 193500000 is the third day in 1970, at 05:45 in the morning in the GMT timezone.

Comment: I've get it now :/ I did not think about it

Comment: As an aside, even for correct/supported uses, I recommend you don’t use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with. And additionally includes a `Duration` class exactly made for your purpose (though unfortunately it doesn’t lend itself that well to formatting).

Comment: There are already a number of answer on Stack Overflow that may help, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36379046/5772882).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert milliseconds to "hh:mm:ss" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027317/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-hhmmss-format)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a duration in java? (e.g format H:MM:SS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266825/how-to-format-a-duration-in-java-e-g-format-hmmss)

Comment: Usage: A [*timestamp*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) is defined as a representation of *when* an event happened. Though it may for example be a count of milliseconds since the Epoch of Jan 1, 1970 UTC, I gather that this is not what you’ve got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

193500000 -> 05hours:45minutes (Wrong, correct is 53hours:45minutes)
That's because 53 hours = 2 days and 5 hours

60300000 -> 16hours:45minutes (correct)
63900000 -> 17hours:45minutes (correct)

108000000-> 06hours:00minutes (Wrong, correct is 30hours:00minutes)
That's because 30 hours = 1 day and 6 hours

117000000 -> 08hours:30minutes (Wrong, correct is 32hours:30minutes)
That's because 32 hours = 1 day and 8 hours

If you only want to calculate the number of hours from ms:

```
193500000/(1000*60*60)   = number of hours  
(193500000/(1000*60))%60 = number of remaining minutes
```

Comment: You are right sir, I've didnt thought of this in that way. Thanks !

Comment: The java.time classes are seaside, and make your code more self-documenting.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is impossible with `SimpleDateFormat`.
"HH" means hour in day. If you date is more than 24 hour it will result modulo 24.

I suggest you to write custom code with new time API.

Here is example:

```
    Duration duration = Duration.ofMillis(193500000);

    long minutes = duration.toMinutes() % 60;
    long hours = duration.toHours();

    System.out.println("" + hours + "hours:"+minutes+"minutes");
```

Comment: For Java 9 and later, see the simplification found in the [answer by Ole V. V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48274434/642706)

Answer (score 2):

Carefully read this again: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

The HH is hours in a **day**, never more than 24 :-)

What you want is probably something like this:

```
    int msecPerHour = 3600*1000;
    int hours = totalTime/msecPerHour;
    int msecPerMinute = 60*1000;
    int minutes = totalTime/msecPerMinute - hours*60;
    String str = "" + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes";
```

Answer (score 2):

[The answer by talex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48260170/5772882) is correct that you should use a `Duration` for this. In Java 9 formatting the `Duration` has become a bit easier and more straightforward to write and read:

```
public static String formatDuration(long totalTimeMillis) {
    Duration totalDuration = Duration.ofMillis(totalTimeMillis);
    return String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,
            "%02d hours %02d minutes",
            totalDuration.toHours(),
            totalDuration.toMinutesPart());
}
```

We no longer need the modulo operation (or similar) for finding the minutes. To demonstrate I called the above method using your time values from the question:

```
    System.out.println(formatDuration(60300000));
    System.out.println(formatDuration(63900000));
    System.out.println(formatDuration(108000000));
    System.out.println(formatDuration(117000000));
    System.out.println(formatDuration(193500000));
```

It prints the results you asked for:

```
16 hours 45 minutes
17 hours 45 minutes
30 hours 00 minutes
32 hours 30 minutes
53 hours 45 minutes
```

I have put in a space between the number and the unit, I find it more readable that way, you can just remove it if you don’t want it.

The `%02d` specifier in the format string makes sure you get two digits with a leading zero as necessary as in the question: `formatDuration(14700000)`, for example yields `04 hours 05 minutes`.

`SimpleDateFormat` was meant for formatting a date and/or a time of day, not a duration or elapsed time. I say “was” because that class is now long outdated, and since it was also notoriously troublesome I recommend you never use it again. For formatting a date or hour of day use a `DateTimeFormatter` from `java.time`.

Answer (score 1):

### `SimpleDateFormat` is the wrong class for this requirement

Your requirement is to calculate the duration instead of a date-time. `SimpleDateFormat` or `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` (part of the modern date-time API) should be used to represent a date/time/date-time i.e. something which represents a point in time instead of a period/duration of time. A thumb rule to remember this is:

1. Use `SimpleDateFormat` or `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` for something which you refer with `since` in English grammar Tense.
2. Use [Period and Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html) for something which you refer with `for` in English grammar Tense.

Check [The Difference between Since and For – English grammar](https://www.wallstreetenglish.com/blog/the-difference-between-since-and-for-english-grammar-with-exercises/)

In order to get the duration from milliseconds, you can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Duration duration = Duration.ofMillis(193500000);
        // Default format
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%02d hours %02d minutes", duration.toHours(),
                duration.toMinutes() % 60);
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%02d hours %02d minutes", duration.toHours(), duration.toMinutesPart());
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT53H45M
53 hours 45 minutes
53 hours 45 minutes
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to convert durations, not date-times. `SimpleDateFormat` is for formatting date-times into different formats for different Locales.

You might be looking for something like this for converting between durations:

```
String.format("%d hours, %d minutes", 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - 
    TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis))
);
```