# Json time duration formatting issue in java

Tags: java, android, json

Is there any way that I could convert time in this format `2640 Hrs : 00 Mts` to `14:22:57 hrs`.

I tried a lot of ways and nothing seems to be working. I really need help.

Json Array

`{"ElapsedTime":"2642 Hrs : 59 Mts"}`

Code I tried

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(jsonDate);
return dateFormat.format(date);
```

The above code throws this exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2640 Hrs : 00 Mts" (at offset 4)
```

I'm using *Volley GsonRequest* and I'm able to parse it but unable to format time.

Comment: This is not *time*, but rather *duration*. In java8 you can use class java.time.Duration. But you still need to parse it manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a duration in java? (e.g format H:MM:SS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266825/how-to-format-a-duration-in-java-e-g-format-hmmss)

Comment: Seems you're missing the moment from when it is elapsed (elapsed since when?)... what are you going to do with that time?

Answer (score 1):

To me that is not a known time format, and is not "normalized", meaning it gives you 2642 hours, that doesn't fit into a 24 hours clock.

So I would go with manual parsing, something like :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]*) Hrs : ([0-9]*) Mts");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(jsonString);
int hours = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
int minutes = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
long time = (hours * 60) + minutes; // In minutes
time *= 60000; // In milliseconds
return dateFormat.format(new Date(time));
```

I have not tested this code, so YMMV, but you should get the idea.

Comment: try it:  *SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");  
  System.out.println(format.format(new Date(26 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));* Result is: 03:00:00

Comment: I tried it, but it throws an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far
java.util.regex.Matcher.ensureMatch(Matcher.java:596)
java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:357)