# Print a Duration in human readable format by EL

Tags: java, jsp, java-8

First of all I'm new to `java.time` package.

I'm writing a webapp that need to work with specific times of the day and with several durations of events.

So I wrote my code using `LocalTime` and `Duration` classes of `java.time` package.

When I need to render their value in JSP it is very simple for `LocalTime` object (because `.toString()` returns a human readable vale), so I can just write `${startTime}` and everything goes in the right way (e.g. it is rendered as `9:00`).
The same approach doesn't work for Duration, because its representation is something like `PT20M` (in this case for 20 minutes).

Does it exist an elegant way to perform a human-readable conversion in JSP directly by EL?

Yes, I know I can convert the object in a string in my classes (before JSP), but I'm searching for the suggested approach (that I'm not able to find)... another point is that I not see an official "convert()" (or whatever else) method in Duration object... so I'm thinking I'm using the wrong object to map a duration of time (to add or subtract on `LocalTime`s).

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need a formatted textual duration only in English or also in any other language (like "1 Stunde und 20 Minuten" in German)? If other languages are important then I recommend to use an extra 3rd-party-library. Java-8 does not contain any built-in duration formatting, see also the correct answer of @Erlandsson which is sufficient if you only need a numerical form.

Comment: In truth I just need a 20 for 20 minutes, or 1:20 for 1 hour and 20 minutes... nothing to do with localization, just a human readable form...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there exists no elegant builtin way to format a `Duration` in Java 8. The best i have found is to use the method *bobince* describes in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/266970/423991) answer:

```
    Duration duration = Duration.ofHours(1).plusMinutes(20);
    long s = duration.getSeconds();
    System.out.println(String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", s/3600, (s%3600)/60, (s%60)));
```

Which prints:

> 1:20:00

The code will have to be tuned if you need longer durations.

I'm not sure what you mean that you are missing a `convert` method, but `Duration` is well suited for adding/subtracting on `LocalTime`. The methods `LocalTime.plus()` and `LocalTime.minus()` accepts `Duration` as argument.

Comment: Thank you... I'm exactly using duration only to represent the duration of an event (so, if the LocalTime is 9:00 an there is a duration of 30 mins, I can use what you wrote to get another LocalTime as a summation: 9:30). Speaking of something like a "convert()" method, I'm just referring to the absence of a method to convert the Duration object in a String representation (that is again the topic of the question... it is only a repetition). By the way... it is very strange to don't have a taglib or someting else to do what I need for Duration, but LocalTime perform this simply by its toString()

Comment: At the end I decided to create another get method in my bean, that will be used on demand by my EL code: I wrote  `${item.myDurationStr}` instead of `${item.myDuration}`, and it will "convert" the format, with a code like

`public String getMyDurationStr() {`
`long sec = myDuration.getSeconds();`
`return String.format("%02d:%02d", sec/3600, (sec%3600)/60); // I don't need for seconds`
`}`

Answer (score 6):

If you're interested in words, apache commons will do the trick:

```
 DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationWords(System.currentTimeMillis() - start, true, false))
```

```
 2 days 1 hour 5 minutes 20 seconds
```

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DurationFormatUtils.html#formatDurationWords-long-boolean-boolean-

Comment: Nice one, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!