# Java getDuration(2.5d, TimeUnitType.Hour) no return duration in format ISO8601

Tags: java, time, duration, java-time

I need duration in format ISO8601. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations.

Example :

```
double dur = 1442.7; //hrs
java.time.Duration d = java.time.Duration.ofMinutes((long)dur.convert(0).toDouble());
System.out.println(d.toString());  //// **1- issue of truncate real number ???**
```

2- I notice MsProject in the tag Value of Duration expects to always have a duration value of the ISO8601 form but at least with "H, M and S" (example: PT4H0M0S) whereas in this case Java.time.Duration return "PT4H" which is not valid for MsProject and this gives me the figure that we have nothing to what I expected. **????**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this but you can format it manually by adapting the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/266846/829571):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  double dur = 1442.7; //hrs
  java.time.Duration d = java.time.Duration.ofMinutes((long) dur);
  System.out.println(format(d)); //PT24H2M0S
}

public static String format(java.time.Duration duration) {
  long seconds = duration.getSeconds();
  long absSeconds = Math.abs(seconds);
  String positive = String.format(
          "PT%dH%dM%dS",
          absSeconds / 3600,
          (absSeconds % 3600) / 60,
          absSeconds % 60);
  return seconds < 0 ? "-" + positive : positive;
}
```