# how to make a time format in -01:-05:00 to -01:05:00

Tags: java

After subtracting time 1:10 and 2:15 using java I am getting the ouput as long which is in milliseconds -3900000. Then I convert this millisecond into time format, then the output produced is 
Output : -01:-05:00.

The output I am expecting is like -01:05:00.
There should be only one negative sign in the output

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TimeAddition {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        String b = "1:10";
        String a = "2:15";

     // converting String time into dateTime   
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date bTime = sdf.parse(b);
        Date aTime = sdf.parse(a);

        long totalTime = bTime.getTime() - aTime.getTime();

        System.out.println("Total time in millisecond = " + totalTime);

        long millis = totalTime;

        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                    - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                    - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));

        System.out.println("Time format " + hms);   
    }

}
```

Output produced :
Total time in millisecond = -3900000
Time format -1:-5:00

Expected Time format = -01:05:00

Comment: Please add your code so we can see what's wrong and advise for correction.

Comment: make the milliseconds to positive and then change into time format, after then put a negative sign in front of it.

Comment: Well, hard to tell the problem from text only. Please show the code you use to convert the milliseconds into time (only that part ;) ). PS : try to edit the question to improve the format. Using some tags to see the values you have

Comment: I cannot add the negative sign to the final output because its output will be either positive or negative, it can't be predicted

Comment: Related (not a dupe): [How to format a duration in java? (e.g format H:MM:SS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266825/how-to-format-a-duration-in-java-e-g-format-hmmss/18633466)

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like that:

- you compute if you should add a sign (-) or not.
- if the amount of time is negative, you get its absolute value (you can also use `Maths.abs`).
- you format it with the sign before.

Which gives:

```
String sign = totalTime < 0 ? "-":"";
long millis = totalTime < 0 ? -totalTime:totalTime;
String hms = String.format("%s%02d:%02d:%02d", sign, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                       - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                        - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Change this code :

```
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis))
```

to this code:

```
TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)) - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
```

[image: Tested successsfully]

Comment: it appears wrong when time is  String b = "0:10"; String a = "0:15"; the input time can be any

Comment: the output should be -00:05:00, here output appears as 00:-5:00

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach as well to get time difference easily.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     String time1 = "01:10:00";
     String time2 = "02:15:00";
     String finalDiff;

     try{
          SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
          Date date1 = format.parse(time1);
          Date date2 = format.parse(time2);

          long difference = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
          Date d;

          if(difference<0) {
              d = new Date(-1*difference);
              finalDiff = "-"+ format.format(d);
          }
          else{
              d = new Date(difference);
              finalDiff = format.format(d);
          }

          System.out.println(finalDiff);// gives the difference as required by you.

     }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Comment: The output producing does not meat my need

Comment: as i mentioned you  have to place a `negative` based on whether `difference` is positive or negative.

Comment: check now @ShamithSKumar

Answer (score 0):

`Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are both oldfashioned and unsuited for the purpose. They were intended for a point in time and its representation in a certain timezone, never for the length of a time interval. I would not be comfortable using them for the latter, or I would at the very least test thoroughly on computers running different time zones.

My suggestion is to use the new `java.time` package. Despite the fact discussed in the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/266846/5772882) that it does not include a duration formatter.

```
    String b = "1:10";
    String a = "2:15";

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm", Locale.ROOT);
    LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse(b, dtf);
    LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse(a, dtf);
    Duration totalTime = Duration.between(start, end);
    String sign;
    if (totalTime.isNegative()) {
        totalTime = totalTime.negated();
        sign = "-";
    } else {
        sign = "";
    }
    long hours = totalTime.toHours();
    totalTime = totalTime.minusHours(hours);
    long minutes = totalTime.toMinutes();
    totalTime = totalTime.minusMinutes(minutes);
    long seconds = totalTime.getSeconds();
    System.out.format("%s%d:%02d:%02d%n", sign, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

This prints:

```
-1:05:00
```

The price is we need to handle a negative interval explicitly. The good news is the library classes do all calculations for us: calculating the length of time and conversion to hours, minutes and seconds.