# Convert number of seconds into HH:MM (without seconds) in Java

Tags: java, datetime, time, datetime-format, java-time

I'm aware that you can use `DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(seconds)` to convert a number of seconds into a `String` with the format `HH:MM:SS`. But are there any utility functions that let me perform the same conversion but without the seconds?

For example, I want to convert `3665` seconds into `1:01`, even though it's exactly `1:01:05`. In other words, simply dropping the seconds part.

Would *strongly* prefer an answer that points to a utility function (if one exists) rather than a bunch of home rolled algorithms.

Comment: Make use of `java.time.Duration`

Comment: I believe the utility function exists in [Time4J, the advanced date, time, zone and iInterval library for Java](http://time4j.net).

Comment: I believe you can find a lot of inspiration from searching. For just one exampe there’s a near-duplicate here: [How to format a duration in java? (e.g format H:MM:SS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266825/how-to-format-a-duration-in-java-e-g-format-hmmss). With an answer using the Time4J library I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the available information, you seem to be wanting to format a duration based value.  Lucky for us, since Java 8, there is now a new `java.time` API which includes a `Duration` class.

Unfortunately, it doesn't (at least the last time checked) support a formatter for it.

However, you could easily roll your own...

```
protected static String format(Duration duration) {
    long hours = duration.toHours();
    long mins = duration.minusHours(hours).toMinutes();
    return String.format("%02d:%02d", hours, mins);
}
```

Which when used with something like...

```
System.out.println(format(Duration.ofSeconds(3665)));
```

prints out `01:01`.

Now I know you'd *"prefer"* utility methods, but you're unlikely to find something that fits your "every" need and this at least gives you a starting point.  Besides, you could always make a pull request ;)

Comment: No bunch of home rolled algorithms here. The calculations take place in the library. I agree that this is advantageous.

Comment: This is great, especially using `String.format()` to format the output. The answers I found while searching were mostly just int-division, modulus and concatenating strings, resulting in loss of leading zeros. That's what I meant by "home rolled algorithms".

Comment: @BadCash Oh dear lord no - if there is one thing that will attract my downvote - it's date/time arithmetic - There is no excuse for it, especially these days

Answer (score 4):

## Use Apache [Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

You could use utility class [`DateFormatUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateFormatUtils.html) of Apache's well known utility library [Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), combined with [TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#toMillis-long-) to convert from seconds to milliseconds:

```
static String format(long durationSeconds) {
    long durationMillis = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(durationSeconds);
    // Commons lang:
    return DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(durationMillis, "HH:mm");
}
```

Use with input `3665` it prints:

> 01:01

Personally I'd prefer to use Java8 or Java9 standard library (see the other answers) rather than introducing a dependency just to make it 1 method call.

Comment: Makes sense Ole, changed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

[MadProgrammer has already provided a good Java 8 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50096554/5772882) (which will work in Java 6 and 7 too when you use the ThreeTen Backport). In Java 9 still a bit more of the calculation can be done in the library:

```
    int seconds = 3665;
    Duration dur = Duration.ofSeconds(seconds);
    String formatted = String.format("%d:%02d", dur.toHours(), dur.toMinutesPart());
    System.out.println(formatted);
```

Output:

> 1:01

The `toMinutesPart` method and other `toXxxPart` methods were introduced in Java 9.