# How to change seconds into hours and hours value must not exceed 24 hours.?

Tags: java

I have written a program to change seconds value into seconds, minutes, hours, and Days. All other values are giving exact output except Hours. Whenever a user gives more than 86400 value it gives more than 24 hours value which I don't want.
..

```
int days = totalSeconds / 86400;
totalSeconds -= days * 86400;
int hours = totalSeconds % 3600;
totalSeconds -= hours * 3600;
int minutes = totalSeconds / 60;
int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: You need to carry forward the remaining into days

Comment: Use `Duration`...

Comment: Don't allow the User to supply a value higher than 86400. A simple **If** statement should take care of that.

Comment: Use `Duration` as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096083/convert-number-of-seconds-into-hhmm-without-seconds-in-java/50096554#50096554)

Comment: If you know how to get minutes (0-59), then what is the problem of doing the same for hours (0-23)?

Comment: I cant do that.. I have to work according to my assignment and it says accept any value except negative values

Comment: because for minutes i divided seconds by 60 and then again by 60.. This does not help in case of hours if i double divide by 3600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with `totalSeconds` as an `int` to be broken down into seconds, minutes, hours, and days, this sequence should work with hours maxing out at 23:

```
int days = totalSeconds / 86400;
totalSeconds -= days * 86400;
int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
totalSeconds -= hours * 3600;
int minutes = totalSeconds / 60;
int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
```

Comment: worked like a charm.. Thanks all

Comment: All I ask is an up-vote. :)