# error in getting correct hours and minutes

Tags: java

```
public class Testdate_time {

public void testdate() throws ParseException {

    String in_time = "2018 May 07 09:20:01 AM";
    String out_time = "2018 May 07 10:08:29 AM";
    int hours = 0;
    int mintues = 0;
    org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy MMM dd hh:mm:ss a");
    DateTime date1 = format.parseDateTime(in_time);
    DateTime date2 = format.parseDateTime(out_time);
    hours = Hours.hoursBetween(date1, date2).getHours();

    String strhours = String.valueOf(hours).replaceAll("-", "");
    mintues = date1.getMinuteOfHour() - date2.getMinuteOfHour();
    String Strminutes = String.valueOf(mintues).replaceAll("-", "");
    System.out.println("hours" + strhours);
    System.out.println("minutes" + Strminutes);

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    new Testdate_time().testdate();

}
```

i have used jodatime also and simpledateformat
http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html

**Output:**

```
hours0
minutes12
```

Comment: Because you’re getting minutes separately, so your minutes output is 20 - 8, hence 12.

Comment: #but why not hours calculating()

Comment: There is less than 1 hour between `09:20` and `10:08`, so `hoursBetween()` returns `0`. There is 12 minutes between `08` and `20`, so `minutes = 12`. What's so hard about understanding that?

Comment: Because there isn’t one full hour between your dates.

Comment: @notyou  hours = Hours.hoursBetween(date1, date2).getHours() and not calculating in hours

Comment: @VivekSrivastava It *is* calculating hours between, and less than 1 is **0**.

Comment: Re read my comment above, and also @Andreas ‘

Comment: BTW: You don't say what you expected. You should be expecting a good calculation to say `0 hours 48 minutes`, but for that you should calculate `diff = minutesBetween()`, not discard the sign, and calculate `hours = diff / 60` and `minutes = diff % 60`.

Comment: I have downvoted because you don’t specify expected result and because you don’t show any search and research effort (I believe you should have been able to find a number of similar questions and answers with a moderate effort).

Answer (score 1):

To correctly calculate hours and minutes between two dates, using Java 8 Time API and ignoring Daylight Savings Time, you'd do it like this:

```
String in_time = "2018 May 07 09:20:01 AM";
String out_time = "2018 May 07 10:08:29 AM";
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu MMM dd hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDateTime.parse(in_time, format);
LocalDateTime date2 = LocalDateTime.parse(out_time, format);

long diff = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(date1, date2);
System.out.printf("%d hours %d minutes%n", diff / 60, diff % 60);
```

Or, if you don't want to do the math yourself, use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html):

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(date1, date2);
System.out.printf("%d hours %d minutes%n", duration.toHours(), duration.toMinutesPart());
```

*Output (from both)*

```
0 hours 48 minutes
```

Comment: Maybe I just hate any kind of arithmetic applied to date/time values, but you could do something more [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096083/convert-number-of-seconds-into-hhmm-without-seconds-in-java/50096554#50096554) which relies entirely on the API

Comment: @MadProgrammer Added `Duration` solution too.