# Java turning calculated milliseconds of time left into human readable time (years, months, days, etc...)

Tags: java, datetime

I'm trying to countdown to a time in the future (2024) and I have the time left from the users system to the exact date in 2024.

```
 String input = "Mon Apr 08 2024 18:18:29 UTC";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(input);
long milliseconds = date.getTime();
long millisecondsFromNow = milliseconds - (new Date()).getTime();
```

That is my code, im trying to turn `millisecondsFromNow`into a date a human can read, more specifically, years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds left until the date.

Comment: What is exactly your problem? How can we help you?

Comment:  Never, ever, ever perform simple mathematic arithmetic against time values, you are going to end up in a world of pain.  Since Java 8, we've had the new date/time API, there's even a back port API which supports earlier versions of Java so there is simply no excuse any more

Comment: Do you want to have the difference between two points in time? Then have a look at: [Calculating the difference between two Java date instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Comment: The classes you are using, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, are long outdated and also poorly designed. I recommend you drop those and look into [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) for a replacement. You want `DateTimeFormatter`, `Period`, `Duration` and one or two more classes. There’s guidance in some of the answers to the linked questions. You may also look into `PeriodDuration` from the ThreeTen Extra library (use your search engine).

Comment: @M.Fuchs I have that code and `millisecondsFromNow` is a big, big number, so I'm trying to turn that number from milliseconds into the number of years, months, days, etc. left. What I need help with is just the converting of the milliseconds. Don't know if that was any clearer but I think these guys pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score -1):

You can create a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) object using the [`ofMillis`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#ofMillis-long-) method. Then have a look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/266825/437621) for formatting options.