# How to format a Period in Java 8 / jsr310?

Tags: java, java-8, period, time-format

I'd like to format a [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) using a pattern like `YY years, MM months, DD days`. The utilities in Java 8 are designed to format time but neither period, nor duration. There's a [`PeriodFormatter`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html) in Joda time. Does Java have similar utilities?

Comment: No, java.time does not have a similar capability.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266825/how-to-format-a-duration-in-java-e-g-format-hmmss

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One solution is to simply use [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-):

```
import java.time.Period;

Period p = Period.of(2,5,1);
String.format("%d years, %d months, %d days", p.getYears(), p.getMonths(), p.getDays());
```

If your really need to use the features of [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), you can use a temporary [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), but this is a kind of hack that distort the semantic of [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

Period p = Period.of(2,5,1);
DateTimeFormatter fomatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("y 'years,' M 'months,' d 'days'");
LocalDate.of(p.getYears(), p.getMonths(), p.getDays()).format(fomatter);
```

Comment: I don’t like seeing `LocalDate` used as a hack. Why not do the same placeholder with value replacement approach using the String facilities in Java?

Comment: I agree that distorting the semantic of `LocalDate` is not elegant and could lead to problems.

Comment: @BasilBourque I agree in general, but it seems to me that it's a workaround for a weakness in the JDK Api, which should allow the `DateTimeFormatter` to accept any `TemporalAmount`.

Comment: The problem with this (that Joda solves) is that your string is not localized.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to use `String.format()` for simple string formatting. Using plain old string concatenation will be optimized by JVM:

```
Function<Period, String> format = p -> p.getYears() + " years, " + p.getMonths() + " months, " + p.getDays() + " days";
```

Comment: Only wondering what would be wrong with a plain old method declaration in this case?

Comment: Personally, I think the `String.format()` version is easier to read in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static final String format(Period period){
    if (period == Period.ZERO) {
        return "0 days";
    } else {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        if (period.getYears() != 0) {
            buf.append(period.getYears()).append(" years");
            if(period.getMonths()!= 0 || period.getDays() != 0) {
                buf.append(", ");
            }
        }

        if (period.getMonths() != 0) {
            buf.append(period.getMonths()).append(" months");
            if(period.getDays()!= 0) {
                buf.append(", ");
            }
        }

        if (period.getDays() != 0) {
            buf.append(period.getDays()).append(" days");
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

the proper way seems to be an intermediate LocalDate object and then calling format

```
date1.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu MM LLLL ee ccc"));
OR (where appropriate)
date1.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu MM LLLL ee ccc", Locale.CHINA))
```

this prints `1997 01 一月 07 周六` in chinese, `1997 01 January 01 Sun` in english and `1997 01 januari 07 zo` in dutch.

check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html under "Patterns for Formatting and Parsing" for your desired formatting.