# Bind simpleStringProperty to a simpleIntegerProperty using custom asString method

Tags: javafx, binding

I have a simpleIntegerProperty representing a quantity in seconds which I want to represent in hh:mm:ss format.

I'd like to render this in a Label via binding the Label textProperty to the simpleIntegerProperty.  I understand I can do something similar to this with format strings, e.g.

```
activeTimeText.textProperty().bind(model.activeTimeSeconds.asString("Seconds: %04d"));
```

renders:

```
Seconds: 0000
```

So the question, how to implement a more complex asString conversion?  For example my current desired output output (where the digits are functions of the seconds simpleIntegerProperty.):

```
00:00:00
```

I've searched for an a similar question already as I feel this should be quite common.  However have not found the answer.  Apologies if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`NumberExpression.asString(String)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/NumberExpression.html#asString(java.lang.String)) formats the number according to the rules of [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html), same as if using `String.format` or `Print[Stream|Writer].printf`. Unfortunately, unless I'm missing something, the `Formatter` class expects date/time objects to represent a *moment* in time, not a *duration* of time. To format your property as a duration with a `HH:MM:SS` format you'll need to create your own binding.

To get the `String` you want you can still use `String.format`, but by formatting as integral numbers rather than time. This requires you to calculate the hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
String str = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

If you're using Java 9+, calculating the hours, minutes, and seconds is made extremely easy with [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html); the class had the `toHoursPart`, `toMinutesPart`, `toSecondsPart`, and other similar methods added in Java 9. If using Java 8 you'll need to do the calculations manually or pull in a library, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266825/how-to-format-a-duration-in-java-e-g-format-hmmss) for some help in that regard.

Here's an example assuming Java 9+ and using [`Bindings.createStringBinding`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createStringBinding(java.util.concurrent.Callable,javafx.beans.Observable...)) to create the binding:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  private final IntegerProperty seconds = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "seconds");

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Label label = new Label();
    label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
      // java.time.Duration
      Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(seconds.get());
      return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHoursPart(),
          duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart());
    }, seconds));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(label), 500, 300));
    primaryStage.show();

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(javafx.util.Duration.seconds(1.0), e -> seconds.set(seconds.get() + 1))
    );
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can extend `SimpleIntegerProperty` to override `asString`:

```
class MySimpleIntegerProperty extends SimpleIntegerProperty{

    @Override
    public StringBinding asString(){
         return Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> " hello " + get() ,    this);
    }
}
```

To test use:

```
MySimpleIntegerProperty activeTimeSeconds = new MySimpleIntegerProperty();
activeTimeSeconds.set(7);

SimpleStringProperty activeTimeText = new SimpleStringProperty();
activeTimeText.bind(activeTimeSeconds.asString());
System.out.println(activeTimeText.get());
```

You can of course delegate the value processing to a method:

```
@Override
public StringBinding asString(){
    return Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> processValue(get()), this);
}

private String processValue(int value){     
    return " hello " + get() ;
}
```