# Looking for Java formatted time utils

Tags: java, time, formatting, timestamp

I am looking for a time utils for java where I can give a time in seconds or in milis and it'll return with methods for for example `getSeconds` and `getMinutes` so I can easily format the text to look like `Remaining 1 day 2 hours 3 minutes and 4 seconds`.
Does anyone know any?

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: Maybe `java.time.Duration`

Comment: If you only need days max (ie, not months), then this just requires few divisions, no need for a library for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a duration in java? (e.g format H:MM:SS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266825/how-to-format-a-duration-in-java-e-g-format-hmmss) (you can trivially adapt the answers from there to give you `1 day 2 hours 3 minutes and 4 seconds`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour and 24 hours in a day so:

```
private static final int SECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 60;
private static final int SECONDS_IN_HOUR = 60 * SECONDS_IN_MINUTE;
private static final int SECONDS_IN_DAY = 24 * SECONDS_IN_HOUR;
```

Then you just need to keep on dividing:

```
class RemainingTime {
    private static final int SECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 60;
    private static final int SECONDS_IN_HOUR = 60 * SECONDS_IN_MINUTE;
    private static final int SECONDS_IN_DAY = 24 * SECONDS_IN_HOUR;

    private int totalSeconds, days, hours, minutes, seconds;

    public RemainingTime(int totalSeconds) {
        this.totalSeconds = totalSeconds;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        int remainingSeconds = totalSeconds;
        days = remainingSeconds / SECONDS_IN_DAY;

        remainingSeconds -= days * SECONDS_IN_DAY;
        hours = remainingSeconds / SECONDS_IN_HOUR;

        remainingSeconds -= hours * SECONDS_IN_HOUR;
        minutes = remainingSeconds / SECONDS_IN_MINUTE;

        remainingSeconds -= minutes * SECONDS_IN_MINUTE;
        seconds = remainingSeconds;
    }

    public int getDays() { return days; }
    public int getHours() { return hours; }
    public int getMinutes() { return minutes; }
    public int getSeconds() { return seconds; }
}
```

You use it like this:

```
RemainingTime rt = new RemainingTime(274119);

System.out.println(String.format(
        "Remaining %s day(s), %s hour(s), %s minute(s) and %s second(s)",
        rt.getDays(), rt.getHours(), rt.getMinutes(), rt.getSeconds()));
```

Outputs:

```
Remaining 3 day(s), 4 hour(s), 8 minute(s) and 39 second(s)
```