# how do I shorten this

Tags: java, eclipse

is there any way to shorten this code?
In the code, times of microseconds are converted into minutes and seconds. For example 305862000 ms = 05:05 (5 min : 5 sec).

```
public static String timeFormatter (long microtime) {
    String time = null, timemin = null, timesec = null;
    long min = 0;
    long sec = 0;

    // check if time is negative
    if (microtime < 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Negativ time value provided");
    } else {
        min = (long) (microtime/(Math.pow((double) 10,(double) 6))/60);
        if (min < 10) {
            timemin = "0" + min;
        // check if time is too long
        } else if (min > 99) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Time value exceeds allowed format");
        } else {
            timemin = min + "";
        }
        microtime = (long) (microtime - min*60*Math.pow((double) 10, (double) 6));
        sec = (long) (microtime/Math.pow(10, 6));
        if (sec < 10) {
            timesec = "0" + sec;
        } else {
            timesec = sec + "";
        }
        time = timemin + ":" + timesec;
    }
    return time;
}
```

Comment: FYI: `ms` is **milli**-second. **Micro**-second is abbreviated as `μs`. See [List of SI prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix#List_of_SI_prefixes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) to format numbers with leading zeroes.

```java
public static String timeFormatter(long microtime) {
    if (microtime < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative time value provided: " + microtime);
    if (microtime >= 6000000000L/*100 mins*/)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Time value exceeds allowed format: " + microtime);
    long seconds = microtime / 1000000;
    return String.format("%02d:%02d", seconds / 60, seconds % 60);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Calculation

```
long milliseconds = microtime/1000;
Duration durationInMilliseconds = Duration.ofMillis(milliseconds);
```

## Formatting

Using Apache Common DurationFormatUtils: https://github.com/apache/commons-lang

```
boolean padWithZeros = true;
DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(millis, "**mm:ss**", padWithZeros);
```

Without a library (from Zabuzard's comment), see:

[How to format a duration in java? (e.g format H:MM:SS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266825/how-to-format-a-duration-in-java-e-g-format-hmmss/44343699#44343699)

Comment: Note that the formatting can also easily be done without a library, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44343699/2411243) for details.

Comment: sorry I´m a beginner, is this what you have written everything I need?
how can I add the checks if its negative or to long

Comment: What is `DurationFormatUtils`? If your answer is to use a third-party library, the answer is only useful if you *name* and *link to* the library.

Comment: It is literaly in the comment right above it. But i'll add a more explicit link.

Comment: "link to" as in something you can click.

Comment: Added it, better like this?

Comment: Very much so, yes.

Comment: Thanks for advice, still pretty new to answering on SO.