# Kotlin/Java how to format localized time duration like "1 minute 30 seconds"?

Tags: java, kotlin, datetime, date-formatting, duration

Is there a way to format a localized time duration in Kotlin or Java? I have a Duration, and I want to display it in a localized, human readable string like "1 minute 30 seconds" or "1m 30s".

I did find [RelativeDateTimeFormatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/RelativeDateTimeFormatter), but it only appears to generate time parts that are in the future or past tense like "1 minute ago" or "in 1 minute". Is there a way to configure it to generate the present tense?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, none of the answers in the linked question are localized.

Comment: Interesting… The Unicode [CLDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) ([used by modern implementations of Java](https://openjdk.org/jeps/252)) does indeed seem to offer localization data for [duration values such as *minutes*](https://unicode-org.github.io/cldr-staging/charts/42/by_type/units.duration.html). I am voting to re-open.

Comment: I suggest you add a link to documentation on this `RelativeDateTimeFormatter ` class you mention. I do not see it bundled with Java SE.

Comment: Joda seems to have had classes for formatting Period.  It's odd that these didn't end up in java.time.  (Of course, that doesn't deal with the localisation, but it's half of the issue).

Comment: As the other comments seem to indicate, I believe that this is not built into Java (probably not Kotlin either).

Comment: Did you check [How to format a duration in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/266825/10819573)?